# The response json contains class name after the tag

Tags: json, spring-boot, webclient

The response body JSON contains class name after each tags while through postman its all correct.
Why in Java program its behaving this way. Same code was returning request in correct json format earlier.

Below is the snippet:

ResponseEntity response = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(resourceUrl).queryParams(queryParams).build())
.headers(headers).retrieve().toEntity(Test.class).block();

Response Structure has:

```
stat: **class Stat** {
   
}

Tests: [**class Test** {
    A: **class A** { ....
```

It should not have class names like this. Not able to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is this this much only, there is no Object Mapper used. It's just a simple service call with query params. The response returned in response entity, has class names associated with each and every tags. While the same response returned through postman is a normal JSON format.